# Prevent alt text of an img tag from being rotated when the image is not found

Tags: html, css

I have applied `transform: rotate(90deg);` CSS on my image, but it is also rotating ALT text, which is causing this text to appear over other image whenever image is not found.

Is there any why in which I can prevent ALT text from getting rotated?

```
<div>
<img style="transform: rotate(90deg);" alt="User Name" src="http://ImageURL">
</div>
```

[image]

```css
div { margin-top:50px; }
```

```html
<div>
    <img style="transform: rotate(90deg);" alt="User Name" src="http://ImageURL">
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

I am having a lot of images on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `onerror` handler to remove the styles from your image:

```js
function onImageNotFound() {
  document.getElementById('imgTest').style.transform = 'none';
}
```

```css
div { margin-top:50px; }
```

```html
<div>
    <img id="imgTest" style="transform: rotate(90deg);" alt="User Name" src="http://ImageURL" onerror="onImageNotFound();">
</div>
```

And here is an inline version:

```css
div { margin-top:50px; }
```

```html
<div>
    <img style="transform: rotate(90deg);" alt="User Name" src="http://ImageURL" onerror="this.style.transform = 'none';">
</div>
```

Comment: This is a fun idea but the alt text may also be displayed when an image is slow to fetch or render. I'd rather use the onerror callback to *add* the alternative text (as a rich element).

Comment: That's not the most usual case but it happens and that's how it's designed. See [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img): "or if the image is not yet downloaded"

Comment: @klugjo thanks for the response, but MDN article say "not to use onerror method" ... Should I go with it ?

Comment: @nbi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image I don't see anything in MDN

Comment: @klugjo [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: You are right. As of now I don't know any other solution though .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images. What I did seems to be what everybody else does as well. You could look at jQuery

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is probably to apply the transformation only on *loaded* images:

```js
for (let img of document.querySelectorAll("img")) {
  img.addEventListener("load", function(){
    this.classList.add("rotated");
  });
}
```

```css
div { margin-top:50px; }
.rotated { transform: rotate(90deg); }
```

```html
<div>
    <img alt="User Name" src="http://ImageURL">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="User Name" src="https://dystroy.org/spacebullet-48.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only applying the effect to one (small) image you could do something like this with CSS.

Place a non-rotated copy of the image behind the rotated image. If the image loads, the rotated version will show. If it fails, the alt text of the non-rotated version will show.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  /* hide the broken image icon */
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.img-rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* hide the alt text */
  color: transparent;
}

.img-copy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p>Broken image link</p>
<div>
  <img class="img-rotate" alt="User Name" src="http://ImageURL">
  <img class="img-copy" alt="User Name" src="http://ImageURL">
</div>

<p>Working image link</p>
<div>

  <img class="img-rotate" alt="User Name" src="https://unsplash.it/200">
  <img class="img-copy" alt="User Name" src="https://unsplash.it/200">
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the same on big images: they're cached anyway so this shouldn't be a burden for the browser.

Comment: @DenysSéguret so browser will make only one call for two or more <img> element having same src attribute?

Comment: @nbi right. The DOM is still a little heavy but this looks like a fine solution if you can't use javascript's onload event handler.